# Samsung QN700B monitor loses 8k resolution (stuck 4k) when reconnected/turned back on, forgets settings

Tags: xorg, nvidia, xrandr, edid, samsung

I'm having a problem with a Samsung TV as a monitor. Thank you for any insight:

debian + xorg + RTX4090 + qn700b + (HDMI 2.1 cable seems good)

Problem: when waking the TV and computer, I can't get it back to 8k again? It becomes stuck at 4k.

---

Symptoms:

- Initially, a black screen when TV/computer are turned back on (either order).
- Ctrl-alt-f1/f2/etc wakes screen into 4k, and then I can ctrl-alt-f7 back to graphical tty, but I lost 8k and now it's stuck at 4k (tv correctly still in Samsung game mode).
- `sudo nvidia-settings` doesn't allow 8k (only 4k appears in dropdown)
- downloading EDID via `nvidia-settings` and forcing in xorg doesn't work? Not sure how to tell.
- `cvt` and `xrandr --newmode etc` / `--addmode "HDMI-0" 7680x4320at60` fails with `BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)`, major opcode 140 RANDR, minor opcode 18 `RRAddOutputMode`.

(I know I can set Option "DPMS" "false" and various Options "fooTime" "off" in xorg or `xset -dpms` and keep the monitor on 24/7, or restart the window manager/X/etc as a workaround, but wish to otherwise fix this without losing WM state, without an irreversible firmware update if possible.)

Thank you for any insight!

Xorg.0.log:

```
Validated MetaModes: "7680x4320+0+0{AllowGSYNCCompatible=On}"
..
MetaMode "HDMI-0:7680x4320" could not be re-validated against the current hardware configuration; removing.
..
Setting mode "DPY-0:7680x4320+0+0{AllowGSYNCCompatible=On}"
..
Setting mode "DPY-0:nvidia-auto-select+0+0{AllowGSYNCCompatible=On}"
```

xorg.conf:

```
Section "Monitor"
..
    Option         "DPMS" "false"
    Option         "PreferredMode" "7680x4320"
EndSection

Section "Device"
..
    Option         "ModeValidation" "AllowNonEdidModes"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
..
    Option         "CustomEDID" "GPU-0.HDMI-0:/path/to/edid.txt"
    Option         "metamodes" "7680x4320 +0+0 {AllowGSYNCCompatible=On}"
    Option         "ConnectToAcpid" "False"  # https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=262207
    SubSection     "Display"
        Virtual     7680 4320
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr: TV game mode gets corrupted, so have to go out and back into game mode, but there are multiple game mode settings so you have to be careful which one you use. The command line will help you avoid resetting all the settings each time with the GUI. This happens rarely that it is quite tolerable for me, and the below is a fairly easy workaround.**

(After a failed bounty and some months of agonizing frustration, I am posting my own answer... hope it helps others...)

Do not change any settings yet! These steps are only known to help immediately after loss of 8k resolution. Proceed to read the following.

---

### Situation:

You are unable to set 8k on your Samsung monitor...

1. **despite Game Mode being on, *AND***
2. **despite an HDMI 2.1 cable**, and
3. (perhaps) after previously gotten it work (maybe it works on startup, but you'd like to fix this without restarting the window manager or rebooting) (and maybe you disable DPMS to avoid this situation at the cost of your summer electric bill)....
4. (and maybe your screen is black)

(The following fix is known to work with out-of-the-box firmware, so you don't have to irreversibly upgrade your firmware, though maybe that fixes it (if you do/don't have this problem with updated firmware, please let us know in the comments).)

---

### Background

(In general you can confirm Game Mode is on by either:

1. holding down the ⏯️ button on the remote...

   - which should display a different "totally cool gamer sci-fi UI" horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the screen, showing you VRR and Latency etc.; nothing will happen if not in Game Mode

OR

2. In the horizontal ⚙️ menu, `Game Mode =` should AS USUAL be set to `= Game`...

   - **(do NOT change these yet) (DO NOT CHANGE THESE YET) (DO NOT CHANGE THESE YET)**

     - `Picture Mode =` is auto-set to `= Game` when `Game Mode = Game` is on; and
     - `Sound Mode =` is auto-set to `= Game` when Game Mode is on; and
     - `Game Mode =` is manually set to `= Game` (seemingly-obviously) to enable Game Mode. (also works with `= Auto`)

---

### Solution

I never got xrandr and xorg.conf to force a non-EDID mode in the hopes of tricking the Samsung monitor to behave.

What instead worked was getting the Samsung monitor to realize that, yes, it indeed can do 8k, and advertise it properly again via EDID to the PC:

- (First, if your screen is black, on Linux do `ctrl-alt-f1` to at least be able to see things in 4k, then return to graphical with `ctrl-alt-f7`... I had absolutely no luck going through the Samsung troubleshooting, and it maybe made my problems permanent and I had to reset my TV to default settings.) (If you're not on Linux but on Windows or Mac and for some reason experiencing this, you can maybe make a keyboard shortcut to degrade back to a temporary resolution, or try to proceed with the caveat you're not exactly following these steps.)
- Enter the Samsung settings horizontal scroll menu (hit (⚙️123) button, then either 1) hit it some more, or 2) hit upwards on circular direction pad a few times).
- Go to `Game Mode`, which may be a bit to the right, requiring a few hits rightwards on the circular direction pad. `Game Mode` should be set to `Game` as usual, and Game Mode should be on (verifiable via instructions above).
- **However, THE INTERNAL STATE OF THE SAMSUNG TV and/or its "game mode" may be invisibly bugged. The following will fix it:**
- Go to `Game Mode` (***do NOT confuse with `Picture Mode = Game`; continue hitting right until you get to the THIRD mention of `Game Mode = ...`***) and hit it once; this will set it to `= Auto`. You should still be in `Game Mode` (`= Auto`, verifiable via instructions above), but it's no longer corrupted.

  - **edit:** This should also work if you are in `= Auto`; hit it once to set it to `= Off`, then after it's off hit it again to set it to `= On`
  - *tl;dr:* Turn Game Mode off and back on, being sure not to confuse it with Picture Mode.
- Now, the PC should be able to set 8k resolution via your usual means. e.g.

  - `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 7680x4320` (or whatever it's called in `xrandr` where it should not properly display) will work. I believe this even preserves `{AllowGSYNCCompatible=On}` but if I'm mistaken then
  - set that again in `nvidia-settings` > sidebar=`X Server Display configuration` > `Advanced...` button on bottom > etc.
  - recommended: **alternatively, you can just run the command..............................: `nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="HDMI-0: 7680x4320_60 +0+0 {AllowGSYNCCompatible=On}"`** (presumably you are using HDMI port 0). This is the fastest with ctrl-R on a terminal, and does not require sudo.

(Changing any other settings, such as setting picture mode to entertain or other things by trial and error, caused me to be unable to fix things, unable to re-enter Game Mode, the monitor to detect things incorrectly or swap profiles to blindingly bright settings, etc. until a full reboot. Your mileage may vary.)

---

ALTERNATIVE:

If that messes up and makes the TV forget your settings, then I've had some luck with cycling (like 5 seconds between cycles) from Game Mode `=On` (corrupted) -> `=Auto` -> `=Off` -> `=On`, then invoking `nvidia-settings --assign etcetcetc` as above.